# How to escape from a "continued" gdb without hitting a break point

Tags: c++, gdb

I put a break point to my process and continued gdb. Is there a way to escape from the "continued" gdb process **without hitting the break point**.

Here I want to get back to the state where I can enter new gdb command or add another break point.(escape from "continue" state)

[image: Add a break point and continue]

**Note :** ctrl+c does not work for me either in this scenario.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the phrase "Is there a way to escape..." ? Perhaps an alternative description amended to your question?

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks for the response

Comment: Ah, ok, yeah, you're not entering GDB-command-anything unless the process is paused in the debugger while doing so. I.e, I don't think you can get there from here (but if I'm incorrect, I dearly want to know it as much as you do). Breaking into the debugger is really your only alternative.

Comment: Can you provide more background to _ctrl+c does not work for me either_?

Comment: Do you know why ctrl+c isn't working? Is your process doing some signal handling? Maybe try sending a SIGTRAP to the process or issue `handle SIGINT stop` before continuing.

Comment: To my application ctrl+c wont work.That is, I still see the process is in the continued state

Comment: @LasithaKonara Okay, that probably means the application is using `sigwait` or something. Can you try installing the `SIGINT` handler or sending a `SIGTRAP` with `kill -TRAP <pid>`.

Comment: @TartanLlama  After I enter into the continue state,I cannot enter SIGTRAP or any command right?

Comment: @LasithaKonara Sorry, that `kill` command is a Unix command, not GDB. Enter it from another terminal with the pid of the process you're debugging. The signal handler should be installed (`handle SIGINT stop`) in gdb before issuing the continue.

Comment: @TartanLlama But it will kill the process. I do not want to kill the process. There is a way to kill the process,there is no issue with that. What I need is to return from the continue state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107704/discussion-between-tartanllama-and-lasitha-konara).

Comment: Look up "non stop" mode in GDB. "set non-stop on"

Comment: The gdb process could be killed using following

 1. Open another terminal in the same environment.
 2. Enter command "psu" - this will show the running processes.
 3. Now find the gdb process ID. For an example we will take it as 9864.
 4. Now run command kill -9 9864.
 5. There you have the solution to kill the process.

But what I'm asking is how to get back to the place where we are still on the gdb but not in the continued state